# Чому у слова випадіння є множина, а у випадання немає? Чи є?

Tags: іменники, число

[Словник УЛІФ](//lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua) каже, що у слова *випадіння* є множина *випадінь*, а от у *випадання* немає:

| відмінок | однина | множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **називний** | випаді́ння | випаді́ння |
| **родовий** | випаді́ння | випаді́нь |
| **давальний** | випаді́нню | випаді́нням |
| **знахідний** | випаді́ння | випаді́ння |
| **орудний** | випаді́нням | випаді́ннями |
| **місцевий** | на/у випаді́нні, випаді́нню | випаді́ннях |
| **кличний** | випаді́ння* | випаді́ння* |

| відмінок | однина | множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **називний** | випада́ння |  |
| **родовий** | випада́ння |  |
| **давальний** | випада́нню |  |
| **знахідний** | випада́ння |  |
| **орудний** | випада́нням |  |
| **місцевий** | на/у випада́нні, випада́нню |  |
| **кличний** | випада́ння* |  |

Це недопрацювання словника чи дійсно є якась причина?

Comment: думаю, що це недопрацювання словника, але хай краще хтось з філологів скаже

Answer (score 1):

В інших подібних джерелах є множина слова *випадання*.
Просто її не використовують, неможливо знайти приклад його використання у множині. Дії та процеси вживають в однині.

Слово не приживається і не використовується, коли звучить неприродно для самих носіїв мови або просто з непотрібності, нелогічності, коли рука або язик самі не тягнуться сказати речення: *"Такі випадання звуків можуть свідчити про..."*, - бо набагато грамотніше буде: *"Такі випадки/приклади випадання звуків можуть свідчити про..."*.

Множина слова *"випадіння"* теж непотрібна.

І те, і те - процес. Його не потрібно рахувати, як фізичні предмети. На практиці тільки перелічують  різні процеси, а не один і той самий. Напр., *"Продукт проходить декілька процесів виробництва: збирання, очищення, висушування, підготовка, термічна обробка..."*. Як бачите, так само важко сказати *"збирань", "очищень", "висушувань"*, а кажуть *"декілька етапів очищення/висушування/термічної обробки"*.

Джерела: [Словник.UA](https://slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F),
[Aztekium](http://aztekium.pl/find.py?lang=uk&q=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).

P.S.: Я порівняла ці два слова в Google Trends, і він показав, що в пошукових запитах слово випадання набагато менш популярне за випадіння, а слова випадань та випадінь узагалі відсутні серед пошукових запитів.

Comment: Тобто Ви пропонуєте замість «кількість випадінь герба» писати щось типу «кількість випадків випадіння герба» — я правильно розумію?

Comment: Пишуть "кількість випадань герба", "кількість разів випадання герба", "число випадань герба"(це в задачі з теорії ймовірності), "частота випадання герба".

Comment: Або я щось не до кінця зрозумів, або наведені Вами приклади «кількість випадань герба» і «число випадань герба» заперечують Ваше твердження, що множина цим словам непотрібна. (Чи я щось неправильно зрозумів?)